# Visual C++ accessible private destructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider a simple example (note that the destructor is private):

```
class Resource {
private:
    ~Resource() = default;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Object on the stack
    Resource r1; // line L1

    // Object on the heap
    Resource* r2 = new Resource();
    delete r2; // line L2

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this snippet in MSVC 2017 produced, as I'd expect, two C2248 errors on lines L1 and L2 saying that the `~Resource` destructor cannot be accessed.

Now if we add another primitive field to the `Resource` class, say an `int`:

```
class Resource {
private:
    int x = 0;
    ~Resource() = default;
};
```

the compilation result suddenly changes: now the L1 line no longer gives an error, only L2 does.

If instead of a primitive type we'd use a class member of a more complex type, like a `vector`, the second compilation error would be back again.

And finally, if instead of defaulting the destructor we'd explicitly provide an empty body:

```
class Resource {
private:
    ~Resource() {};
};
```

then the 2 errors would be present in all of the above cases.

The same snippets compiled with GCC and Clang always produce 2 errors for both destructors.

So the question is:
even though it could just be a compiler bug, I suspect that this behaviour might have something to do with the class being or not being an aggregate based on the fields and the destructor being user-provided or not.
What could be the actual reason for this behaviour? Or to be more precise: is it ever OK for the compiler to ignore the privateness of the destructor?

**Edit**: here's a link to this setup on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/weXZkp). This behaviour can be seen by (un)commenting the `int x = 0;` line.

Comment: I get both errors with your 2nd example in VS.

Comment: As for defaulting the dtor vs providing an empty user-defined one, see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor read the bit about "*trivial* destructor".

Comment: Here's a link to [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/weXZkp) with the second example - you can see the number of errors changing as you (un)comment the `int x = 0;` line.

Comment: @UKMonkey Which version of VS are you using?  I only get one error in the 2nd example with VS 2017 v15.5 (`Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.12.25830.2 for x86`), which is newer than the one in the godbolt setup.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm 2015 - 14.0